# Why is my cloud explosion white?

Tags: particles

Please find the blend file attached.  I've been looking at tutorials for making cloud explosions (regular explosions are something I'm also using in the project, but I want the specific look of the explosive cloud).  No matter what I do it renders white rather than the "gray with sullen red glow" look that the tutorials say the Explosion option for the Cloud Generator is supposed to produce.  There is a light in the scene.  What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Later edit:

thanks for your response!

So it's just not possible to get this:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jsjGIDsRqRM

Or is that a result of directional lighting plus a change in scatter color? Doing what he did definitely didn't give me his result.  His looks like there's only light coming from deep inside the cloud, not all over it.

If anyone else ends up having the same question, I never did get the effect I wanted with this, so I ended up instead going with a more complex three-mesh setup using quick smoke: a domain, a smoke mesh, a flames mesh, and a flame particles mesh, where the flames and particles meshes fit inside the smoke cloud mesh and were slightly different in shape to get that irregular flames-inside-smoke look I wanted.  This is reliable enough when the meshes are hires enough to sculpt, which also adds a look of more detail to the billows of smoke. It means the cloud shape is more artificial than generated, but it does give the level of control I wanted for the specific application I needed it for.

I'll attach that blend file too, in case anyone searches the question and is equally confused/frustrated with their attempts.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

As You could see on the picture below, the **Scatter Color** value (green circle) is the point of your interest. Changing this values leads to different cloud scatter colour. Please keep in mind that **scatter colour settings is reversed** so if You want a red clouds You have to **lower** the red value.

*(values used on the image: R=0.55, G=0.62, B=0,65)*

[image]

Hope it helps You, Buddy.